# kotlin generic type ,the difference with BaseResp<BaseCode.Data> and BaseCode:BaseResp<BaseCode.Data>

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

```
class BaseCode: BaseResp<BaseCode.Data>() {

    inner class Data {
        var code = 0
    }
}

open class BaseResp<T> {
  
    var data:T? = null
}

interface IMessageCallback<T> {

    fun onMessage(data:T)
   
}

inline fun <reified T:BaseResp<Any>> send(cb: IMessageCallback<T>?){
}

fun test(cb:IMessageCallback<BaseCode>?){
      send(cb)
}
```

The compiler error:

> The BaseResp<BaseCode.Data> is different with BaseCode:BaseRest<BaseCode.Data>

and then I changed to this:

```
inline fun <reified T> send(cb: IMessageCallback<BaseResp<T>>?) {

}

fun test(cb:IMessageCallback<BaseResp<BaseCode.Data>>?) {
        send(cb)
}
```

This is right but it is not easy for other callers and looks tedious

Smart guys come across this scenario and how to solve it。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of `send` requires the caller to pass in `BaseResp<Any>` or a subtype. This would allow passing in an instance of something like

```kotlin
class Sample: BaseResp<Any>()
```

but not

```kotlin
class Sample: BaseResp<String>()
```

In short, `Fee<T>: Foo<T>` works, but `Fee<X:T>: Foo<T>` won't.

If you change your declaration of `send` to

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T:BaseResp<out Any>> send(cb: IMessageCallback<T>?)
```

it'll work. Note the `out Any` - this is a covariant type parameter (and is called "Type Projection"), and treats a `BaseResp<String>` (or any other type in place of `String`) as a subtype of `BaseResp<Any>`.

Now you can use `BaseResp<String>` as well as `Sample`.

Note that because we've defined the type of `data` as `out` in the declaration of `send`, you can only *read* the `data` from the `BaseResp` inside `send`, you can't *write* it. This restriction makes it possible to pass in subtypes of that parameter.

(To be a little more general to explain, if your function takes a `MutableList<Animal>`, you could read and write any type of `Animal` to that list. But you could *only* pass in exactly a `MutableList<Animal>`. If you changed it to `MutableList<out Animal>`, we could now pass in a `MutableList<Dog>` or `MutableList<Cat>` because you're guaranteeing you're only going to read items from that list - `Dog`s and `Cat`s can be read as `Animal`s. But the function has no idea what type is valid to put into that list - all it knows are `Animal`s. Because the incoming list could only store `Dog`s and `Cat`s (and their subtypes), the function using `out` can't be allowed to write to it.)

If the `data` inside `BaseResp` could be a `val`, you could use declaration-site variance to define this for all instances of `BaseResp`. For example:

```kotlin
open class BaseResp<out T>(val data:T? = null)
```

and then you wouldn't need the type projection (the `out` in the declaration of `send`) and you'd have consistent use everywhere. This depends on if you really need `data` to be a `var`; for a response type you can likely make it immutable.

I'd recommend reading [Generics: in, out, where](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html) in the Kotlin docs for more detail.

I have an old recorded [lecture from my Kotlin class](https://youtube.com/watch?v=S3gYgokFJ7w). I need to update it, but it might help.

Comment: Thank you so much,I am  Not enough knowledge of generics

Comment: Generics in any language can be tricky. Kotlin does it really well, but it's a bear to get your head around when variance comes into play. I have an old recorded lecture from my Kotlin class at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3gYgokFJ7w. I need to update it, but it might help.

Comment: That's great. It's what I want